# Hamburger menu, find and tab buttons gone from gnome-terminal in 22.04

Tags: gnome

I have several 22.04 installs, one a fresh install and one a upgrade.  With the upgrade, my gnome-terminal top bar looks like:
[image]

On the fresh install it looks like:

[image]

Never mind the color theme (which I've changed manually), how do I configure the updated system to have the top bar menu and action icons?  I've looked and dconf and tweaks and don't see explicit settings for these.  So clearly there's something going on at the theme level.  But the themes in tweaks are the same on both machines.   Not a big deal, but I like new mode better.

Answer (score 1):

Still, you looked in the right place. In dconf-editor, head to org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings headerbar, and set it to "true"  to have client side decorations like in your second image.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Turns out that that 'headerbar' was the first thing I tried.  Didn't matter.  And it's set to 'nothing' on the machine that works, too.

Comment: Just as an experiment, I tried changing the 'headerbar' values on the first install, and it doesn't change the top bar either.

Comment: I use Gnome Terminal without the headerbar, and I set the value to False to that effect, also on 22.04. You need to close then reopen the terminal, but I suppose you did that as well.

Comment: Thanks.  The problem seems to be Wayland vs X11.  When I use Wayland, it behaves exactly as you found.  I had turned this to False on X11 because there is a resizing bug; every every full screen->normal size cycle, the terminal decreases its row and column number.  Ugly.   When I set it back to True (or Nothing), the behavior was unchanged in X11 oddly.  However, the resizing bug seems to be gone from 22.04 Wayland, but not 22.04 X11.  Sigh.  Anyway, I can use Wayland.  I had an application that was working poorly under Wayland (ParaView) but the latest version seems okay.   Crazy making.

Comment: Strange how our mileages seem to vary. I am actually running on Xorg. I also cannot reproduce the issue with the changing size of the terminal window you describe.

Comment: Huh?!  There's a launchpad bug on this so other people besides me have this issue.  But clearly not everyone (like you).  And I had it on two installs but not a third.  Although the third was a fresh install so that make me think that there is some config cruft somewhere but nothing obvious.  The bug has been reported many times, so it exists under some peculiar as of yet undetermined circumstances.

Comment: It will be good if you can provide the link then.

Comment: Sure the link is: [launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1288655)

Comment: Yes, I see. In Gnome Boxes, I can reproduce it in Xorg, not in Wayland. Never noticed it on my main system because I do not use the header bar. Strange how it appears impossible to fix such a reproducible bug, reported back in 2014.